# Mdadm. Disk already part of an array

Tags: mdadm

I am trying to delete my RAID array and start again because of some annoying error listing my gpt is corrupt. I used gparted to delete all the info off the disks, so they say "unallocated" on each drive. I then try to create an array using the commands below, but it always says "/dev/sdX appears to be part of a raid array". How do I fix it? It is not part of an array, there isn't even a file system on any of the disks!

```
$ sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=5 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
mdadm: /dev/sda appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sda but will be lost or
   meaningless after creating array
mdadm: /dev/sdb appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdb but will be lost or
   meaningless after creating array
mdadm: /dev/sdd appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdd but will be lost or
   meaningless after creating array
mdadm: /dev/sde appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sde but will be lost or
   meaningless after creating array
mdadm: /dev/sdf appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdf but will be lost or
   meaningless after creating array
```

One user suggested it was some superblock problem and asked me to zero the superblock, but the command doesn't work as shown below:

```
$ sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for pc: 
mdadm: Unrecognised md component device - /dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because `mdadm` still finds the superblock of the old raid. You can easily delete it running

```
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdX
```

Comment: main post updated. This command doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try with --force? The man page says: "With --force the block where the superblock would be is overwritten even if it doesn't appear to be valid."